# Trouble with MvvmCommunityToolkit Badge in .NET MAUI: Badge Not Reflecting on Google Pixel Mobile

Tags: c#, mvvm, notifications, maui, badge

I am attempting to display the number of notifications on the app icon using a badge. However, it is not functioning as expected. I am following the official documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/essentials/badge?tabs=android) for the Badge, but permissions for Google's Pixel mobile are not provided.

I Used badge provided by MvvmCommunityToolkit in viewModel

```
 private readonly IBadge badge;


 public RequestViewModel(IBadge badge)
 {
     this.badge = badge;

 }

 [RelayCommand]
 private async Task ViewDetails()
 {
     badge.SetCount(2);
 }
```

when this command is getting hit this badge set the counting on app icon as provided in documentation

In MauiProgram.cs

```
 var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
 builder
     .UseMauiApp<App>()
      .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
     .RegisterAppServices()
     .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
     .RegisterViewModels()
     .RegisterViews()
     .ConfigureMopups()
     .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
     {
         fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
         fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
         fonts.AddFont("fa-solid-900.ttf", "Icons");
         fonts.AddFont("Poppins-Regular.ttf", "Poppins");

     });
 builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();
 builder.Services.AddSingleton<IBadge>(Badge.Default);
```

Comment: This Badge API comes from the .NET MAUI Community Toolkit not the MVVM Toolkit.

What is your question here? Are you asking what the permissions are for the Google Pixel? I can see the documentation states the toolkit does not provide it all because it can different for each flavour of Android

Comment: The Mvvm Toolkit was written mistakenly. Yes, I want to know how to use this for Google Pixel mobile. What permissions do I need to add, or did I make another mistake?

Comment: I don't know what the answer is but hopefully knowing that is what you are looking for, it will help others reading it